# is the Matlab radon() function a "circular" radon transform?

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to translate some matlab code to python. In the matlab code, I have a radon transform function. I start with a 146x146 image, feed it into the radon() function, and get a 211x90 image. When I feed the same image into my python radon() function, I get a 146x90 image. The documentation for the python radon () function says it is a circular radon transform. Is the matlab function also circular? Why are these returning different shaped images and how can I get the outputs to match?

Answer (score 0):

Matlab's radon() function is not circular. This was the problem. Although the output image sizes do still differ, I am getting essentially the result I want.